# Array Formula for column totals

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I know how to use an array formula to auto apply a formula down a column, but I was wondering if you could do the same but along a row?

I have tried to apply the sample princple i.e rather than a range for the column, I use the rang for the row, but the sum totals are incorrect. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

There is a colum per month which will auto exapand every month, with the latest month in colum B. These total are used in other sheets, so I want to avpid having to have to rember to update the new row tih sum total: Can the same principle of array formula which auto populates cells in a column, be applied to rows?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try this in Cell_A5 of the sample datset:*

```js
={"total_",bycol(indirect("B2:4"),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,sum(Σ))))}
```

- *added `indirect()` with an assumption that a new column maybe inserted at column_B to insert new/latest month data*

[image]

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks so much. So array formula cant be used to expand across a row then?

Comment: yeah arrayformula works across rows as well; its just the use of lambda formulas make it kinda easy-peasy is all!

Comment: Thanks all, so helpful. One last thing that I am trying to do is rather than sum, subtract two values. I have tried altering the formula you provided, but nothing I have tried seems to work. So same principle, except I want to subtract 2 numbers from each other and have the formula work across the row and still work if an additional column is added as the initial solution provided.

Comment: Share a test sheet recreating this scenario and also showcase the expected output(*manually entered*)

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow, thought I wold create it as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693438/auto-expanding-minus-in-column

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why an array formula shouldn't expand across a row - you could do this for example:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(range,indirect("b2:4"),{"Sum",if(indirect("b1:1")="","",sumif(range*0+column(range),column(range),range))}))
```

[image]

...but now that lambdas are available there is no reason to do so!