# Auto expanding minus in column

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have two rows, one is total expenses and the other total income, I wam wanting to use arrayforumula type function but by row. So for example, income less expenses should display in a row called balance and auto minus all other columns. The columns also auto expand eaxh month, so would be great if I didnt have to re-enter the formula.

Very similar to the help I received in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649251/array-formula-for-column-totals/76649281?noredirect=1#comment135212396_76649281), except rather than summing a range in a column, its subtracting two values in a column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fOaSSdWXrW7QTG3xC9e6TTvQV5jo6WNu5bYDJIQvCIM/edit?usp=sharing

[image: example]

I tried using the formula offered for the sum column range by replacing sum with minus, that didnt work. I tried multiplying the value by -1, that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
={"Balance",map(indirect("B2:2"),indirect("B3:3"),lambda(exp,inc,if(counta({exp,inc})=0,,inc-exp)))}
```

- *added `indirect()` with an assumption that a new column maybe inserted
  at column_B to insert new/latest month data*

[image]

Comment: Thanks once again, that works perfectly. I am not even away of half the functions used, probably should take a course or something. Thanks again, have an awesome weekend

Comment: maybe this vid here could give a refresher on [map / lambda](https://youtu.be/kUur-tMdTbo) usage and all.